# Store text from dynamically created textareas in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Problem - I have 2 buttons `addNew` and `submitText`. I have created a javascript function for each of these two buttons. The `addNew`creates textareas with unique ids `(note0, note1...)`. The `submitText` is supposed to submit the text from all the dynamically created textareas in localStorage in the (key, value) format `(notesList0, data), (notesList1, data)` and so on. The code is as follows -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var note_id = 0;
  $("#addNew").click(function () {
     note_id++;
     var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width:80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');
      $('#textFields').append(inputField);      
  });

  document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var id=0, counter;
     var flag=true;

     for(counter=0; counter<=note_id; counter++) {
         var textData = document.getElementById("note"+counter).value;
         alert(textData);
         while(flag==true)
         {
             if(localStorage.getItem("notesList"+id)!=null) {
                 id++;
             }
             else {
                 localStorage.setItem("notesList"+id, textData);
                 flag=false;
                 alert("Text saved");
             }
         }
     }
 } , false);
 });
```

The `addNew` works but `submitText` only saves value of the first textarea. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the HTML too, as that would make it easier for us to understand and debug.

Comment: Sure. In a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because of flag staying "false" after the first loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var note_id = 0;
  $("#addNew").click(function () {
     note_id++;
     var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width:80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');
      $('#textFields').append(inputField);      
  });

  document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var id=0, counter;
     var flag=true;

     for(counter=0; counter<=note_id; counter++) {
         var textData = document.getElementById("note"+counter).value;
         alert(textData);
         while(flag==true)
         {
             if(localStorage.getItem("notesList"+id)!=null) {
                 id++;
             }
             else {
                 localStorage.setItem("notesList"+id, textData);
                 flag=false;
                 alert("Text saved");
             }
         }
         flag = true;
     }
 } , false);
 });
```

Comment: It worked. Feel silly for overlooking such a small detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for the submit function to make it work for dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitText", function(){
  // Do stuff
})
```

Make sure the ID is only used once on the page. Otherwise switch to class definition.

Comment: Problem is, its only saving first textarea, and not really the 'click'.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var note_id = 0;
  $("#addNew").click(function () {
     note_id++;
     var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width:80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');
      $('#textFields').append(inputField);      
  });

  document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var id=0, counter;

     for(counter=0; counter<=note_id; counter++) {
         var flag=true;
         var textData = $("#note"+counter).val();
         if(textData != undefined && textData != '') {
            while(flag==true)
         {
          if(localStorage.getItem("notesList"+id)!=null) {
                 id++;
             }
             else {
                 localStorage.setItem("notesList"+id, textData);
                 flag=false;
                 alert("Text saved");
               }
            }
         }
     }
 } , false);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="addNew">Add new</span>
<span id="submitText">Submit</span>
<div id="textFields"></div>
```

In case you get error when executing the code, check this link:
 [Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window'](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

Comment: The html section is a miss. But nice addition, to check if textarea is empty or not. Will definitely use it. Thanks.